# docker for ubuntu xenial stop at 1.8?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu xenial-updates, and I see that the package manager has a very old version of docker-compose (1.8.0), while Ubuntu cosmic has a more recent version 1.21.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=docker-compose&searchon=names

Why is the docker-compose not up to date on the package-manager for ubuntu xenial?

I installed it without apt, as explained here, and it works correctly.
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xenial was released in 2016.  Cosmic was released in 2018.  Look at the timeline of the Docker Compose releases and compare.

#### References:

- [Docker Compose release notes](https://docs.docker.com/release-notes/docker-compose/)

  ```
  1.21.0 (2018-04-11)
  ...
  1.8.0 (2016-06-14)
  ....
  ```
- [Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: I see; so the packages for Xenial are not being updated any more? should I update to Cosmic...

Comment: If you're developing on Xenial you should stay on Xenial.  Doing what you already did makes the most sense.  But in general, the versions of software only change during major releases (mostly for maintaining compatibility).